# cannot set option of the select using angular js code?

Tags: angularjs, select

I had following html

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Role</label>
    <div class=" col-sm-8">
        <select type="text" id="role" name="role" ng-model="role" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="">Select Role</option>
            <option ng-repeat="rol in rolelist" value="{{rol.id}}">{{rol.title}}</option>
        </select>
        <p class="ng-invalid" ng-show="addForm.role.$error.required">Role need to selected</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to set value of role dynamically clicking data-sets for the purpose of update and setting value of dom element (control); to do so i had following code inside controller

```
$scope.data_set=function(id)
        {
            BlockUi();
            url=siteurl+'/admin/'+module+'/get-info';

                $http({
                    url     :   url,
                    method  :   "POST",
                    data    :   {"id":id}

                }).then(function(responseText){
                    data=responseText.data;
                    $scope.first_name=data.first_name;
                    $scope.user_id=data.id;
                    $scope.last_name=data.last_name;
                    $scope.user_name=data.user_name;
                    $scope.role=data.role;

                    $scope.email=data.email;
                    $scope.contact_number=data.contact;
                    $scope.image_file=data.image;
                    $scope.status=data.status;

                    UnblockUi();
                },function(error){
                    UnblockUi();
                    UnknownError();
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                });
        }
```

above code works for all but **role** model; I watched and follow other question's solutions but did not work for me?

and ng-required error is removed after this code;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for effort of everybody
Actually i strayed every where, but solution is simple ; its problem with datatype; actually select: role model contains string datatype and always ; i am setting the integer datatype to role model which is wrong; i convert the datatype of the data of json to string and set the value of role model works fine.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you look into the ng-options directive? You'll want to do something along the lines of:

```
<select ng-model="role" ng-options="rol as rol.Title for rol in rolelist">
    <option value="">Select Role</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working when you use the code I suggested?

Comment: not setting the value of select; it show list of roles in select but won't work for settting its value dynamically?